# The getter 'isNull' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx and getstorage package while executing following flutter code. I want to check if a variable is null, however I get following error. Variable named variable is not stored on disk while executing below code.

> Exception has occurred.
> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isNull' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: isNull)

**screen.dart**

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    var _variable =  userStorage.read('variable');
    print('_variable = $_variable'); 
    // above prints _variable = null
    if(_variable.isNull){
      // do something if its null
      // but results in flutter error
    }
    else{
      // do something else
    }
  },
  child: Obx(() => (Text(
    'variable value='+controller.variable.value,
  )
  )
  )
)
```

**controller.dart**

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var userStorage = GetStorage();
}
```

Comment: Try it this way `if(_variable==null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default value if it's null

```
var _variable =  userStorage.read('variable') ?? "notSet";
if(_variable == "notSet"){
  // do something 
}
else{
  // do something else
}
```